# Maximal order of elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $F$ be a field and $F^{\times}:=F\setminus\{0\}$ is a multiplicative group. Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $F^{\times}$ with order $n$. Suppose $h$ is the maximal order of the elements in $G$. If $h<n$, show that there exists $g\in G$ such that $g^h \neq 1$.

Remark: The conclusion is false but it is used to derive a contradiction in the proof of the well known fact that any finite subgroup of $F^{\times}$ is cyclic.

My attempt:  By hypothesis, let $a\in G$ be the element with the maximal order $h$, i.e. $|a|=h$. So $a^h=1$ and $a$ generates a subgroup $A=\{1,a,a^2,\cdots, a^{h-1}\}$ of order h.  Since $|A|=h<n=|G|$, there must be a $g\in G$ which is not in $A$. I don't know how to proceed to show $g^h\neq1$. Maybe we need a completely different approach.

Comment: I don't think such a $g$ would exist. If it exist, what would be its order? You can start by looking at the first non-cyclic, finite, abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2.$

Comment: It would be a huge problem, because the premise is wrong.  In all finite commutative groups, the order of *every* element divides the maximal order of the elements in the group.  (If $x$ and $y$ in $G$ have orders $m$ and $n$, and $G$ is commutative, then some element of $G$ has order ${\rm lcm}(m,n)$. This need not be true if $G$ is noncommutative.) So there is no such $g$ as described in the post. Either the OP has misunderstood the task to be solved or the task itself was badly written.

Comment: People have commented and answer to your original question. Please ask a separate question instead editing  the original post.

Comment: @MathGuy you deleted your comment, and that now makes the start of my previous comment awkward because it was a reply to what you had written (you said you didn't see why there is a problem). Be careful about deleting comments when the context of later comments depend in part on them.

Comment: Finite subgroups of multiplicative groups of fields are cyclic, so the condition $h < n$ cannot hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least the question makes sense now, so I will answer it. If $g^h=1$ for all $g \in G$, then the polynomial $x^h - 1 \in F[x]$ has degree $h$, but it has at least $|G| = n > h$ roots, contradicting the well known (and easy) result that a polynomial over a field of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots.

Answer (score 5):

This is false.  Example: $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb Z,+)$ has order 4,  the maximal element order is $2$,  and $2g=(0,0)$ for all elements $g$.

Comment: This example is not good: finite subgroups of $F^*$ are cyclic. And your example is not. Anyhow, the assertion in the original post is not correct since the $h$ must be equal to $|G|$, so in fact $n=h$.

Comment: @NickyHekster The OP changed the question, the original question was for a group $G$, not the multiplicative group of a field.

Comment: Ah, that I missed, thanks +1 from me then.

Comment: If one wants to keep an outdated answer (I usually delete my own answers after OP's edits), then I suggest to mention in the answer box that the OP has changed the question.